# Proving that the union of the limit points of sets is equal to the limit points of the union of the sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My instructor gave us an exercise to do, to show that this equality holds:
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k'=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k\right)^{\!\prime}.$$

My thoughts on approaching this question is by contradiction, suppose that there is an element that satisfies the left side of the equality and not the right side. Then there is a deleted ball with radius $r$ such that $B(x,r)$ intersect the left side of the equality is non empty while there is a deleted ball with radius $r$ such that $B(x,r)$ intersect the right side of the equality is empty. Is this the right approach in proving this? This is as far as I can go.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s very easy to show that $A_\ell'\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k\right)'$ for each $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and hence that

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k'\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k\right)'\;;$$

the harder part is showing that

$$\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k\right)'\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k'\;.\tag{1}$$

Proof by contradiction is a reasonable guess, but it’s not needed.

Suppose that $x\in\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k\right)'$; then for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $$x_n\in B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k\;,$$ and it’s clear that the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $x$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a $k_n\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that $x_n\in A_{k_n}$.

- Show that there is an $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:k_n=\ell\}$ is infinite. Let $L=\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:k_n=\ell\}$.
- Show that $\langle n:n\in L\rangle$ is a sequence in $A_\ell$ converging to $x$.
- Conclude that $(1)$ must hold.

Comment: Contradiction is still the better choice in this case.

Comment: @Troy: It makes very little difference: one ends up doing pretty much the same thing either way.

Comment: I apologize for my late follow-up, but may I ask, the mentioned contradiction could appear in the part: _there is an $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ s. t. $L=\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:k_n=\ell\}$ is infinite_ ? If, $\forall\ell\in\{1,\ldots,m\}, L$ would be finite, then the there would be only finitely many terms of the sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\bigcup_{k=1}^mA_k,$ which is impossible, right?

Comment: @Invisible: Not quite. For $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ let $L_\ell=\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:k_n=\ell\}$; clearly $$\bigcup_{\ell=1}^mL_\ell=\Bbb Z^+\,.$$ If each $L_\ell$ were finite, then $\Bbb Z^+$ would be finite, which is impossible. That contradiction proves the first bullet point.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you for your kind reply, but doesn't $x\in\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k\right)'$ imply even the stronger statement $x\in B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\cap\cup_{k=1}^mA_k\color{red}{\setminus\{x\}}$? Then we would also be able to construct a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with infinitely many different terms and force the contradiction I mentioned?

Comment: @Invisible: You’re welcome. Yes, you can argue that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n\in B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^m\left(A_k\setminus\{x\}\right)$, but then you have to prove that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ has infinitely many distinct terms, and *then* you have to use something like my argument for the first bullet point to show that this sequence has an infinite subsequence lying in one of the sets $A_k$. Thus, you actually end up doing more work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can we generalize this result to countable union?

Comment: @MeetPatel: No. Working in $\Bbb R$, let $A_n=\left\{\frac1n\right\}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then $A_n'=\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, but $\left(\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n\right)'=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** Try doing it with two sets and then proceed by induction.

**Detail on reverse inclusion:** Suppose $x\notin A'\cup B'$. Then there is an open set $U$ about $x$ such that $A\cap U\subseteq\{x\}$ and there is an open set $V$ about $x$ such that $B\cap V\subseteq\{x\}$. Then $U\cap V$ is an open set about $x$ and $(U\cap V)\cap (A\cup B)\subseteq \{x\}$, so $x\notin (A\cup B)'$.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way to prove

$\left(\bigcup_k A_k\right)'\subseteq \bigcup_k A_k'$

is as followed.

Say $p\in\left(\bigcup_k A_k'\right)^c$, i.e. $p$ is not a limit point of any of $A_k$, there exists a neighborhood $N(p)$ (a ball of radius $r$ centered at $p$, if you will) that does not intersect any of $A_k$.

This means $N(p)$ does not intersect $\bigcup_k A_k$ either, so therefore, $p$ cannot be a limit point of $\bigcup_k A_k$, i.e. $p\in\left(\left(\bigcup_k A_k\right)'\right)^c$.

As a result,

$\left(\bigcup_k A_k'\right)^c \subseteq \left(\left(\bigcup_k A_k\right)'\right)^c,$

so

$\left(\bigcup_k A_k\right)' \subseteq \bigcup_k A_k'$

Comment: can we generalize this result to countable union?