# Question concerning frontier points of F (the set of frontier points of S)

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble rigorously proving/disproving the following:

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $F$ be the set of the frontier points of $S$. Is it true that the set of frontier points of $F$ is $F$ itself?

I believe I have the general idea, and tried to prove it using a contradiction (assume there is a frontier point not in $F$, therefore it must contain points in $S$ and be in F), but as said I am not certain as to how to fill in the "in-between," as far as definitions, etc go.

I appreciate all and any help. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $F = \overline{S} \cap \overline{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S}$ is the intersection of two closed sets.  Hence $\overline{F} = \cdots$.

In addition, $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$.  (See, for instance, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812301).)